# How to derive the Taylor series for $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ at $ x=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I tried to do it and was able to find the derivative. But when I tried to evaluate the derivative at x=0 I ran into limits that I did not know how to solve for second and third terms. Is there a method to do this using high-school mathematics?

Comment: Take the logarithm, then expand $\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: @user254433 It's nontrivial to exponentiate the resulting series, I think.

Comment: @user254433 the derivative is not the hard part. Evaluating the value of the derivative at x=0 is. It results in a very messy indeterminate form at x=0.

Comment: @archit If you can show that $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}x^n$, then it follows that $x^{-1}\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}x^n$.

Comment: Okay I was able to do that using integration for x<1. But how do we exponentiate the resulting sum? I want something like this "e-ex/2+11*e*x^2/24+..."

Comment: See this for references: https://oeis.org/A055505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) =(1+x)^{1/x},f(0)=e$ then $f$ has a Taylor expansion around $0$, but using derivatives to find this expansion is not a good idea. Instead note that $$\log f(x) =\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^{2}} {3}-\cdots$$ and on exponentiating we get $$f(x) =e\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{x} {2}+\frac{x^{2}}{3}-\cdots\right)=e\left\{1+\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{3}-\dots\right)+\frac{1}{2!}\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{3}-\dots\right)^{2}+\dots\right\}$$ and with some effort we get $$f(x) =e\left(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{11x^{2}}{24}-\frac{7x^{3}}{16}+\dots\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. But I was looking for a more general way. I once received a question at school where I needed the series for (1+x+x^2)^(1/x)

Comment: @archit: for $(1+x+x^{2})^{1/x}$ just note that $\log(1+x+x^{2})=\log(1-x^{3})-\log(1-x)$.