# Convergence of limit sequence involving $e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

I'm interested in the sequence $y_n$, defined for $n=0,1,2,\dots$ according to
$$
y_n=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left((-x)^n\left[\frac1e\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}y_k (-x)^{-k}\right]\right).
$$
The first few values are $y_0=1$, $y_1=\frac12$, $y_2=\frac{11}{24}$, $y_3=\frac{7}{16}$, which are the Taylor coefficients of the function $f(x)=\frac1e(1-x)^{-\frac 1x}$ at $x=0$.

Does this sequence converge as $n\to\infty$, and if so, to what? Is there a simple expression for $y_n$ that does not involve a derivative?

Comment: Where did you find *this*?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the connection to Taylor series; I have added this information to the question now. My question is not a duplicate, because I am interested in whether the sequence of Taylor coefficients converges, and whether a simple expression can be found for the $n$th coefficient.

Comment: Using Ginac, it seems to vary very slowly, the coefficient of $x^{39}$ in $(1+x)^ {1/x}$ is approximately $-0.3763725551906103 * e$

Comment: The denominator for this coefficient is $2^{53}.3^{19}.5^8.7^3.11^2.13^2.17.19.23.29$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers are given in the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04963) referenced in [this](https://oeis.org/A055505) OEIS entry (given in comments to the "duplicated" [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473091/how-to-derive-the-taylor-series-for-1x-frac1x-at-x-0)). An expression for $y_n$ given there is a double sum involving Stirling numbers (of the first kind). For computation, I would probably stay with the recurrence $(n+1)y_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k+2}y_{n-k}$ coming from [multiplying power series in] $f'(x)=f(x)g'(x)$ where $g(x)=-\ln(1-x)/x-1$.

If we know that $y_n$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n=\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}(1-x)f(x)=1/e$ is easy.

Comment: Thank you! This is enormously helpful.